# Openlayers 4 trigger select feature on map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a website where do you have a map and a list of the regions in the map.

I added the select event on the map when you click on the region.

```
// add select features to the map
map.addInteraction(select);

var selectedFeatures = select.getFeatures();

selectedFeatures.on(['add', 'remove'], function() {
  var names = selectedFeatures.getArray();
  var areasel = [];
  names.forEach(function(feature) {
    areasel.push(feature.getProperties().Name);
    var theCode = feature.getProperties().Code;
    $('#bt'+ theCode).click();
  });
}); // end on select
```

Of course when it selected the feature change color.

How can I trigger the same event when I click on the list?

```
  $('<p>', {
    text: '...'
  }).appendTo('#li' + s.code);
  $('<button />', {
    id: 'bt' + s.code,
    class: "custbtn live",
    text: "Live",
    url: s.url
  }).click(function(e) {

  // Which function do I need to parse?
  // At this point I can have the Name of the feature that i want to select 
  // s.name but how can I use it to trigger the event on the map?

  }).appendTo('#li' + s.code);
```

and this is the WFS vector layer.

```
// UK map source
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.WFS(),
  url: function(extent) {
    return 'http://www.trafficorders.uk/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/var/www/vhosts/trafficorders.uk/httpdocs/maps/wfsareas.map&service=WFS&' +
      'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=la_areas&' +
      'outputFormat=text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1&srsname=EPSG:27700';
  },
  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all
});

// UK map layer
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: styleFunction
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what your click() function should do? To select many features at once?

Comment: just select one feature, here a live system in OL2 http://www.trafficorders.uk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you simply tried to push the feature in your `selectedFeatures` array?

```
var selectedFeatures = select.getFeatures();

$('<p>', {
    text: '...'
  }).appendTo('#li' + s.code);
  $('<button />', {
    id: 'bt' + s.code,
    class: "custbtn live",
    text: "Live",
    url: s.url
  }).click(function(e) {

      selectedFeatures.push(s); //if 's' is actually the feature you got from openLayer?

  }).appendTo('#li' + s.code);
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: feature.getId is not a function
    at ol.source.Vector.addToIndex_ (ol-debug.js:60003)
    at ol.source.Vector.addFeatureInternal (ol-debug.js:59958)
    at ol.source.Vector.addFeature (ol-debug.js:59945)
    at ol.source.Vector.<anonymous> (ol-debug.js:60101)
    at ol.Collection.boundListener (ol-debug.js:7277)
    at ol.Collection.ol.events.EventTarget.dispatchEvent (ol-debug.js:7697)
    at ol.Collection.insertAt (ol-debug.js:8341)
    at ol.Collection.push (ol-debug.js:8368)

Comment: Could you log 's' in your click() function? if it's not an ol4 feature, you need to loop through all the features you get on your Layer and find the one with the same ID than 's.id'.

Comment: I don't use any ID, this is the response from the map. <gml:featureMember
>
<ms:la_areas
 
gml:id
="
la_areas.E09000006
"
>
<gml:boundedBy
>
…
</gml:boundedBy
>
<ms:msGeometry
>
…
</ms:msGeometry
>
<ms:Name
>
London Borough of Bromley
</ms:Name
>
<ms:MapColour
>
#FFB0B0
</ms:MapColour
>
<ms:Code
>
E09000006
</ms:Code
>
<ms:ColourCode
>
40
</ms:ColourCode
>
<ms:Hosted
>
0
</ms:Hosted
>
<ms:Traffweb
>
0
</ms:Traffweb
>
<ms:url
/
>
<ms:ShortName
>
Bromley
</ms:ShortName
>
</ms:la_areas>
</gml:featureMember>

Comment: and then when I click on the map I just pass the Name, see code above (areasel.push(feature.getProperties().Name))

Comment: For your first error, you should look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088348/ol-interaction-select-gives-an-error-on-ol-source-vectortile

Comment: that is OL3, I don't find anything about that "featureClass" in OL4 Documentation. P.S. I use WFS request

Comment: Sorry I can't help you on this, I just don't know. I never had such a problem.

Comment: With a couple of console.log I understand that what you push in the array is the complete feature not just the name, based on that I add a getFeatureById and it works.

      var Code = $(this).attr('id').substr(2);
      // get the feature to push into the selected array.
      var sel = vectorSource.getFeatureById("la_areas." + Code);

      // empty the selectedFeatures array.
      for (x = 0; x < selectedFeatures.getArray().length; x++) {
        selectedFeatures.pop();
      }

      // push the feature.
      selectedFeatures.push(sel);